# Manipulate data from two tables using merge or loop through

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables as below and trying to get result as specified using merge. Is it possible?

**Table 1**:

```
 ConID   Table1ID   Q1A    Q2A      Q3A    Active 
 ------------------------------------------------
  100       1           2      Test     1       1
  101       2           3      Test2    1       1
  102       3           4      Test3    1       1
  104       4           5      Test4    1       1
  105       5           5      Test5    1       0
```

There also exists data for row 5 which is inactive in this case instead of updating that row , i need to add new row with same details but a active row. Any suggestions on how to update the script. Identity column exists for table1 so data wont be duplicated.

Compare data from table2 and update data in table 1 while looking through existing records.

**Table2**:

```
Table1ID   E1       E2          E3      
----------------------------------------
1           2      TestData1     1       
2           3      TestData2     1      
3           4      TestData3     1      
5           5      TestData5     1     
6           7      TestData6     0
```

**Result:**

```
ConID    Table1ID   Q1A    Q2A      Q3A    Active 
-----------------------------------------
100         1           2      Test     1       1 -- Rows with Id 1,2,3 already exists in table 1 dont do anything
101         2           3      Test2    1       1
102         3           4      Test3    1       1
104         4           5      Test4    1       0 -- Rows with Id 4 exists in table 1 but not in table 2 update it to inactive
105         5           5      Test5    1       0
106         5           5      TestData5    1       1 -- Rows with Id 5,6 does not exist in table 1  so insert it
107         6           7      TestData6    0       1
```

Comment: whats the logic to generate Test6 value on the last row as well as how are you generating 106,107 values in ConId column.

Comment: I meant TestData5 and TestData6 not Test5 or Test6 sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you generate Test6 since it is not found in any of your tables (only TestData6 in table 2), but i guess it is the same than in table 1 and Q1 = E1 and Q2 = E2 and so on.

Since i don't have a computed column in my script, i generate ConID 107 just by typing it.

```
-- Declare Table Variables. The result will be in table result. You can then merge it into table 1 or do whatever you want

DECLARE @tab1 TABLE ( ConId int, Table1ID int, Q1A int, Q2A nvarchar(100), Q3A int, Active int )
DECLARE @tab2 TABLE ( Table1ID int, E1 int, E2 nvarchar(100), E3 int )
DECLARE @result TABLE ( ConId int, Table1ID int, Q1A int, Q2A nvarchar(100), Q3A int, Active int )

INSERT INTO @tab1 VALUES ( 100, 1, 2, 'Test', 1, 1 )
INSERT INTO @tab1 VALUES ( 101, 2, 3, 'Test2', 1, 1 )
INSERT INTO @tab1 VALUES ( 102, 3, 4, 'Test3', 1, 1 )
INSERT INTO @tab1 VALUES ( 104, 4, 5, 'Test4', 1, 1 )
INSERT INTO @tab1 VALUES ( 105, 5, 5, 'Test5', 1, 0 )

INSERT INTO @tab2 VALUES ( 1, 2, 'TestData1', 1 )
INSERT INTO @tab2 VALUES ( 2, 3, 'TestData2', 1 )
INSERT INTO @tab2 VALUES ( 3, 4, 'TestData3', 1 )
INSERT INTO @tab2 VALUES ( 5, 5, 'TestData5', 1 )
INSERT INTO @tab2 VALUES ( 6, 7, 'TestData6', 0 )


-- Insert the rows from tab1 and tab2 as requested with matching Active State

INSERT INTO @result
SELECT ConId, t1.Table1ID, Q1A, Q2A, Q3A, case WHEN t2.E3 IS NULL THEN '0'  ELSE (case WHEN t1.Active = 0 THEN '0'  ELSE '1' END) END
FROM @tab1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN @tab2 t2
ON t1.Table1ID = t2.Table1ID


-- Duplicate Row with state active if it is inactive in table 1 and found in table 2

INSERT INTO @result
SELECT ConId, t1.Table1ID, Q1A, Q2A, Q3A, 1
FROM @tab1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN @tab2 t2
ON t1.Table1ID = t2.Table1ID
WHERE t1.Active = 0
AND t2.E1 is NOT NULL


-- Insert Rows only existing in Table 2 but not in table 1 with corrected data

INSERT INTO @result
SELECT 107, t2.Table1ID, E1, REPLACE(E2, 'Data', ''), E3, 1
FROM @tab1 t1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN @tab2 t2
ON t1.Table1ID = t2.Table1ID
WHERE t1.Q1A is NULL

SELECT *
FROM @result
ORDER BY ConId
```

This script results in :

```
ConId Table1ID Q1A Q2A Q3A Active

100     1      2    Test    1   1

101     2      3    Test2   1   1

102     3      4    Test3   1   1

104     4      5    Test4   1   0

105     5      5    Test5   1   0

105     5      5    Test5   1   1

107     6      7    Test6   0   1
```

Comment: What i am doing here is creating your result table in 3 steps.
First: Insert all rows found in table 1 and which are not in table 2 with state inactive, then add all rows found in table 1 and table 2 with given state.

Second: Duplicate the row which is inactive in table 1 and found in table 2

Third: Insert modified data only found in table 2.

Comment: This looks lot more complex, can we merge and achieve it.